# Book about people who could walk between planets

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember a book about some future universe where there were lots of planets, and people traveled between them by spaceship, but one character also mentioned that some people found paths or roads in forests and if they kept walking they could end up on another planet. I need to know the name of the book.

Comment: For more information on the Commonwealth Saga, see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/book-id-astronauts-and-lab-students-can-create-portals-through-space and its linked questions.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/sci-fi-novel-that-involves-mind-backups-and-small-group-minds (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 15):

That would be the [Void Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_Trilogy) by Peter F Hamilton -- *The Dreaming Void*, *The Temporal Void* and *The Evolutionary Void*. To a lesser extent, there's also his [Commonwealth Saga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga), set earlier in the same universe -- *Pandora's Star* and *Judas Unchained*. The aliens who walk the paths between stars are called the [Silfen](http://peterfhamilton.wikia.com/wiki/Silfen).

Comment: that sounds likely, although in those books the primary mode of travel on trains through the wormholes, and "traditional" space travel is only rekindled due to the events in the books.

Comment: As I remember from the Commonwealth Saga the Silfen paths were an important element of the plot line but not an important part of human travel. It was considered a dangerous quest with virtually all humans who attempted it being trapped or killed on other worlds. But as @DougT. points out the use of wormholes and trains were the primary mode of transportation, with wormholes connected by clusters.

Comment: Actually, the most extensive, powerful and beautiful explorations and descriptions of the Silfen Paths concept are in the Commonwealth Saga, although there are plenty of pages in the Void Trilogy. I would most highly recommend the Commonwealth Saga before the Void Trilogy in terms of reading order, although all are great in any order.

Comment: In the Void Trilogy, there is a lot of use of space ships, in fact I don't remember much of a mention of trains. And one of the protagonists - Ariminta, the new dreamer, walks the Silfen paths, and is revealed to have a Silfen ancestry. So the Void Trilogy seems like a pretty good match here. Especially as the Silfen paths lead through forests.

Answer (score 4):

You might be talking about Dan Simmons' Endymion Series. The main female character is named Aenea, but the male lead is "Raul Endymion".  In the earlier Hyperion series a series of gates between planets, referred to as the world web, could be traversed through a void, using what they called farcasters. Towards the end of the series Aenea develops the ability to "Freecast" (travel without gates).

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for the what I believe is the same book. It is an individual novel not part of a series and the title was the name of a woman in plural. The woman's name was the main character in one her as she was first introduced not one of the other names she gave to her other selves.  It was something like "The Rachels".

Assuming that all of these details match, the book I was looking for is "The Margarets". Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It may be Robert Wilfred Franson's "[The Shadow of the Ship](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2523009.The_Shadow_of_the_Ship)". There are multiple worlds, linked by "trails" that can be traversed by beast-drawn trains. The story takes place on one of these trains, an expedition in search of what may be a trail-independent ship crashed in-between worlds.

[image]

Comment: The paths weren't in forests, and one really couldn't just walk. You had to bring your own oxygen, though there was a beast of burden that could walk the roads. They were sort of a cross between normal trains and wagon trains. They had to be pressurized and you could only walk away from the road if you were tethered to the wagons. Thank you for mentioning this book, but I don't think it's the one the OP wanted.