# Sci-fi book: two college kids witness man's first landing on Mars with a wormhole/travel machine they invented; they're ultra rich and nigh-immortal

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I can't recall how long ago I read this book, but it starts with 2 college kids using some form of wormhole or instant travel mechanism they invented to personally witness man's first landing on Mars.  The story skips then to them being ultra rich & nigh-immortal due to medical advances.  One lives on a hollow asteroid that is very well appointed, the other more in touch with the world & politics. The story is somewhat light with a bit of mystery & discussion of societal impacts from income discrepancy.

All my recollection of important events in the book are vague.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already; but maybe you could take a look at [thse guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, you may still be able to narrrow the time your read it at a decade or so? Any recollection of the cover? Was that in English, translated? Also, spoilers are totally fine, as it may trigger someone else's memory :) if you want, you cna hide them by preceding them with `>!`, for instance `>! Darth Vader is Luke's father`.

Comment: It's a duplicate for sure.  Mark it as such if that be best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Book ID: Astronauts and Lab Students can create portals through space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18129/book-id-astronauts-and-lab-students-can-create-portals-through-space) (and while we're at it, if someone wants to flesh that dupe-target a bit...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the first of the Commonwealth stories, Pandora's Star, by Peter F. Hamilton.

From [Wikipedia, *Commonwealth Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga):

> The book opens with a short section providing backstory. As part of
>   the first mission to Mars, a team of astronauts exits their spacecraft
>   for the first time, only to see another man standing there, connected
>   to an air hose that leads through a wormhole to a laboratory in
>   California. The wormhole generator's inventors, Nigel Sheldon and
>   Ozzie Isaacs, chose to test it by beating the crew, by moments, to be
>   the first human on Mars. The saga then moves onto the Commonwealth era
>   in 2380, when humanity has used the wormhole technology to colonise
>   several hundred planets across hundreds of light years.

Comment: Thanks all. I appreciate the prompt & accurate responses. I hadn't remembered it as a series so I passed by Hamilton in my library. Mystery solved & I hope I flagged it appropriately for the karma.